# Which languages do I need to build this form & database on wordpress using kinsta as host?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have just started learning html, CSS and JS. I want to build a simple form where I can take a bunch of user inputs, apply a series of logic to it, and then give user an output based on his choices. There will be a lot of variables though like age, education, etc of the user.

Can this be done on wordpress? Do I need to learn php to do this?

Comment: You will most likely, if not certainly need to learn PHP for this since you are using wordpress, if you expect more than one user you will also need a database to store user information

Comment: Thank you. For wordpress and site hosted on kinsta, which database language should I learn, SQL? If I don't want to store user inputs, and just process them there and then, I am assuming then I do not need a database? But will I write this logic on php or JS.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't intend on storing the data for later purposes then the processing can be done with PHP or JS. However, if you want the data processing to not be accessible by the client then you would do it with PHP since it is the language you're coding your server with, but if it doesn't matter then JS is probably a better option due to its speed, and capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You should consider spending some time at Wordpress Developer - https://developer.wordpress.org/

There is a tonne of information there including example. Yes PHP is a must; html, javascript and CSS will accompany that.

Learning SQL is helpful but there are many functions already within wordpress that will do a lot of the SQL for you.